# i installed jetsream to fresh laravel project . but jetstream login and register pages are not in proper view

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream

i installed jetstream in laravel 8 by using documentation but it not displayed proper way.[image]

here is the tailwind.config.js

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme');
`/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
 module.exports = {
content: [
    './vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php',
    './vendor/laravel/jetstream/**/*.blade.php',
    './storage/framework/views/*.php',
    './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
],

theme: {
    extend: {
        fontFamily: {
            sans: ['Nunito', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
        },
    },
},

plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/forms'), require('@tailwindcss/typography')],
```

};

Comment: Probably You have did following:
    npm install && npm run dev
    php artisan migrate

Answer (score 1):

First finish your installation then compile assets:

```
npm install
npm run dev 

Php artisan migrate
```

Afterwards still if it did not work

At the style section of app.blade.php you might be missing:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">
```

Comment: still not working

Comment: Could you Update the question with tailwind.config.js?

Comment: ok i will update